# Conditions for always positive gradient of heat field in evolutionary thermo-elastic system

Tags: finite-element, hyperbolic-pde, model, modeling, numerical-modelling

I am investigating stability and convergence of series of approximations for coupled thermoelasticity problem yielded by one-step recurrent time-integration scheme.

I've managed to show that the one-step time integration scheme ( OSTIS ) is stable and convergent when the gradient of thermal field is positive (energy of heat of a body at every step is not less than energy on the previous time step of OSTIS). **But now I wonder if this is sufficient result or this is unnatural condition?**

- Generally speaking can someone tell the example of thermo-elastic
  process that occurs in nature (or in machinery) where the gradient of
  temperature of a body is always positive?

P.S. As I understand this occurs when the system/body is constantly heated by external source, so that more heat comes is than comes out in every time step.

UPDATE:

I need to know when this is true:
\begin{align}
 & \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta {{t}^{-1}}s({{z}^{j+1}}-{{z}^{j}},{{u}^{j+1}}+{{u}^{j}})\ge 0 \\ 
\end{align}
Here I user the following notation:
\begin{align}
  & \,\theta =\theta (x,t) \\ 
\end{align} is the temperature field over the body in every time;
\begin{align}
 & \frac{\partial }{\partial t}{{\left. [{{\theta }^{\Delta t}}(t)] \right|}_{{{t}_{j}}}}={{\left. {{[{{\theta }^{\Delta t}}(t)]}^{\prime }} \right|}_{{{t}_{j}}}}={{z}^{j}} \\ 
\end{align} and

\begin{align}
 & s(\theta ,\xi )=\int_{\Omega }{\theta \xi dx} \\ 
\end{align}

So basically, my question concerns term

\begin{align} \Delta {{t}^{-1}}[{{z}^{j+1}}-{{z}^{j}}]\ge 0 \end{align}

Are there physical processes where this occurs?

P.S. Meaning of indexes on the top of variables can be understood from here:

\begin{align}
  & {{\theta }^{\Delta t}}(t)={{\theta }^{j+1/2}}+\Delta t[{{\omega }_{j}}(t)-\tfrac{1}{2}]{{z}^{j+1/2}}+\tfrac{1}{2}\Delta {{t}^{2}}{{\omega }_{j}}(t)[{{\omega }_{j}}(t)-1]{{{\dot{z}}}^{j+1/2}}, \\ 
 & {\theta }'(t)={{z}^{j+1/2}}+\Delta t[{{\omega }_{j}}(t)-\tfrac{1}{2}]{{{\dot{z}}}^{j+1/2}} \\ 
 & {\theta }''(t)={{{\dot{z}}}^{j+1/2}}, \\ 
 & \forall t\in [{{t}_{j}},{{t}_{j+1}}]. \\
\end{align}

Comment: Is "the gradient of thermal field" a vector field or a matrix field? What does it mean that the gradient is positive?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you stated the equations and conditions you derived in mathematical terms, rather than just using numbers.

Comment: I've updated the question to include formulas. If they are not clear please tell in that specific place I will update them.

Comment: I see this value is represents something like the acceleration of temperature change - when it is not less that 0?